# User ID Password captured in BURP tool

Tags: security, password-protection, burp

User id and password can be captured in our product using BURP tool,
By passing every request through BURP tool, we are able to see user id password in clear text.

How can we avoid this? This is a security breach and we want to address this quickly.

Even I encrypted password is shown how is that going to help, because encrypted password is correct and even that will work for intruder.

Comment: It sounds like you're using HTTP Basic Authentication, or a home-grown authentication system. Simply don't do that. Please show how your web application's authentication works, otherwise there's nothing useful that can be said about this.

Comment: We are using HTTPS only, only thing is according to BURP documentation, we installed their certificate in browser and every thing is captured like

Comment: It sounds like you are not using HTTPS correctly - you cannot sniff passwords if it is working. Please add more detail _to the question_, as @CodeCaster suggests.

Comment: Or, if this question is now abandoned, please delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Burp breaks all SSL encryption requests and that is why you are viewing user id and password in the clear.[1](http://forum.portswigger.net/thread/181/https-clear-text-password) This is not a security breach, don't forget you have configured your browser to use Burp as a proxy. It will be a security breach if you are using Wireshark and still be able to view password in the clear.

[Burp Developer answer](http://forum.portswigger.net/thread/181/https-clear-text-password)

Comment: Link Broken. Perhaps this has similar answer https://forum.portswigger.net/thread/password-seen-in-clear-text-on-burp-tool-d3e121c9